# Axis configuration for complex type inside SOAP Response

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, axis

I am trying to build a SOAP Web Service using Java, Axis v1.4 and Eclipse J2EE Helios.
I have a WSDL receiving two xsi:string input parameters and dispatching one complex type of three xsi:string elements.
According to Axis documentation (http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Encoding_Your_Beans_-_the_BeanSerializer), I need to modify the default deploy.wsdd and use a beanMapping entry.

The following entry has been appended to the aforementioned file inside ***service*** tag:

```
<beanMapping
    qname="ns2:Complex_code"
    xmlns:ns2="http://ext.system.gr/ExposeCallbackData"
    languageSpecificType="java:com.system.ext.ExposeCallbackData.Complex_code"
/>
```

Nevertheless, the SOAP Response received when invoking the Web Service via soapUI does not contain the SOAP Envelope.
Please note that in case the WSDL specifies a standard XML type (e.g. xsi:int, xsi:string, etc.), the SOAP Envelope is retrieved as expected.

Is there any other configuration step I should perform in order to resolve the issue?